# Can I modify chrome://extensions/ page with JavaScript(user script)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I'd like to use JavaScript to add a search bar for `chrome://extensions/` page, so I created a file called test.user.js, and write scripts in it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       chromeex
// @namespace  chromeex
// @version    v1.0
/* @reason
 * just a test
 * @end
 */
// @match     chrome://extensions/
//
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    alert("haha");
}());
```

But when I load it in Chrome, it said Invalid header, finally I found out that it's `@match chrome://extensions/` that cause the error. Is there a walkaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Chrome extension won't execute in the `chrome://extensions/` directory or on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) or a few other important areas for security.

One easy way to think of it is that if an extension had access to the DOM in your Chrome Extensions page it could remove your ability to uninstall it, which could be pretty nasty for many users. You may want to look at the [chrome.management API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html), however, if you want to build something outside the Extensions page to be able to search through a user's extensions.

`chrome` itself is not a permitted scheme, which is why you are getting an invalid scheme error. [Here's what Google has to say about it](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html):

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (`http`, `https`, `file`, or `ftp`), and that can contain `'*'` characters. The special pattern `<all_urls>` matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme.

So by definition `chrome` as a scheme will not work no matter what. Think of it not as just another web page, but a part of Chrome's UI.

Comment: Actually, they can access to each other with the management api: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html

Comment: Right, I was editing that in as you were adding that comment. In any case, the real biggie is that chrome.management can function outside the extensions page and has many of the permissions, but nothing can run scripts on chrome://extensions/. It's one thing to be able to enable/disable/uninstall extensions and quite another to modify the DOM on the page of last resort for extension uninstall.

Comment: I tried to write an extension with content scripts:http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html.But when I set the match urls in manifest.json with: `"matches": ["chrome://extensions/*"],` it says that the scheme is invalid

Comment: Yes, see my revised comment above. You can certainly manage extensions with chrome.management, and you can put content scripts almost anywhere. But content scripts have the power to modify the DOM and add/remove/change elements, so they're disabled on chrome://extensions and the Chrome Web Store. Chrome has disabled any `"chrome://*/*` matches as invalid schemes.

Comment: Right. And if you add a browser action or a link in the user's favorites menu (which requires `chrome.bookmarks` permission) or a context menu item (`chrome.contextMenus`), you can send the user there as quickly anyway. In the long run it will give you more control over what the user sees without altering the failsafe extensions page.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject a Content Script / User Script in chrome://extensions/ due to security reasons. You can use the [Extension Management API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html) page to create your own extension management extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that page is not "ordinary" web page, it's high security area, where you can't mess around with userscripts. That is what plugins are for.