# Does content_scripts matches "chrome-extension://*/*" work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to run a content script on an iframe with a chrome-extension:// URL. I added a line to my manifest.json that I copied out of the documentation http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

```
 chrome-extension://*/*
```

But when I reload my extension I get an alert:

```
Could not load extension from '/work/sirius/extension'. 
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[2].matches[0]': Invalid scheme.
```

Any idea how to get this to worK?

Comment: As noted in @Konstantin Smolyanin's answer below, the documention now says nothing about ability to inject content scripts to `chrome-extension:` pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I modify chrome://extensions/ page with JavaScript(user script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148487/can-i-modify-chrome-extensions-page-with-javascriptuser-script)

Answer (score 13):

No. Only `ftp:`, `file:`, `http:` and `https:` can be matched by a content script declaration.

Invalid URL patterns at any of the `matches` and `exclude_matches` fields are rejected (generating an error when trying to load the extension).

Invalid patterns at the [`permissions` option in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) are ignored.

If you want to run a script on a tab from your extension, use [`chrome.extension.getViews`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) in your background script. 
Even better, design your extension's pages such that they [effectively communicate with each other](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) <sup>([example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external))</sup>.

Comment: I want to run a content script on an iframe in a web page. chrome.extension.getViews() allows scripts on extensions, not web pages.

Comment: I am implementing a postMessage based communications mechanism to the iframe, but the iframe is not my code. So I want the content_scripts to allow me to inject the postMesssage() endpoint.

Comment: The above link to the 'permissions option in the manifest file' lead me to investigate using programmatic script injection. Unfortunately this won't work either: the web app hosting the chrome-extension:// iframe can't run the extension code required to inject into its iframe. Perhaps I can write a separate extension to programmatically inject when the tab has a matching URL.

Comment: @johnjbarton You'r right. By not seeing an error when trying the permissions option, I assumed that it's a valid value. Upon further investigation, I discovered that no errors are generated for invalid patterns.

Comment: I tried the programmatic injection from an extension. This also fails because the iframes themselves are added programmatically and  chrome.tabs.executeScript() even with "allFrames:true" only fires during the html parsing. Perhaps a content script on the web app that watches for iframes matching the chrome-extension:// url, then messages the background page to call chrome.tabs.executeScript(). But that is over my limit for silly-tricky :-(

Comment: @johnjbarton FYI, I had tested ways to execute code on arbitrary `chrome-*//*` pages, and failed. This observation was included in my updated answer. If you have control over the pages containing the iframe, and access to the iframes are not restricted by the cross-origin policy, use a technique similar to this one: [How can I detect keyboard events in Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9439525/938089?how-can-i-detect-keyboard-events-in-gmail).

Answer (score 8):

I'm having the exact same problem, look at the API http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html  it says clearly that they accept `chrome-extension://*/*` yet they don't.

They need to update the API so as not to confuse people.

Comment: There is an open issue to correct the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153245

Comment: As @Konstantin Smolyanin answers below, the documentation has been updated.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Chrome authors have silently removed the ability for content scripts to be injected into `chrome-extension:` pages. [Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) still says that it works and even contains examples with *chrome-extension:* scheme but actually it doesn't work. So now only `http:`, `https:` and `ftp:` work "from the box" and `file:` can work if user of your extension has enabled this on Extensions (chrome://extensions/) page.

**Update:** now documentation referred above is updated and says nothing about ability to inject content scripts to `chrome-extension:` pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject js to your iframe html(`chrome-extension:` pages) without declaring it in `manifast.json`. The injected js can visit Chrome APIs directly.

iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
<script src="iframe.js"></script>
</html>
```

iframe.js:

```
console.log(chrome); // {loadTimes: ƒ, csi: ƒ, …}
```