# running a userscript on a chrome-extension:// url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

Is is possible for a userscript to run on (`@match`) URLs that begin with `chrome-extension://`, i.e. change other extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  From [the Content scripts, "Match Patterns" documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html):

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with **a permitted scheme** (http, https, file, ftp, or **chrome-extension**), and that can contain '*' characters. The special pattern `<all_urls>` matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme.

(Note that userscripts, in Chrome, are converted to slightly-specialized "content scripts")

Comment: Updates: [Q 10196258](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10196258/331508) and [Q 19042857](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19042857/331508).