# Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When you're writing the manifest.json file, you have to specify `matches` for your content scripts. The `http` and `https` work fine, but if I try to include `chrome://*/*` or any variant of it, I get an error that I'm attempting to use an invalid scheme for my `matches`.

Is it not allowed?

Comment: Do you need this permission for private use, or in a public extension?

Comment: In Chrome 41.0.2272.76 m, `matches: [ "chrome://*/*" ]` was the way to go. Hopefully I won't have any trouble uploading the extension to the store because of this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By default you cannot run on a `chrome://` url page.

However, there is an option in `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls`:

> **Extensions on chrome:// URLs** (Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android)
>   Enables running extensions on chrome:// URLs, where extensions explicitly request this permission.

You still have to specify pages that your extension can run on and wildcards are not accepted - so you have to specify the full URL eg `chrome://extensions/`

Comment: Note that this flag is considered a "bad flag", and will trigger a warning "stability and security will suffer" the next time Chrome is restarted.

Comment: @Metoule: You can add the `--test-type` command-line switch in order to suppress the warning banner.

Comment: I understand it will be strong violation of security but need to know is it possible to run the extension on the Privacy Error page (for example when site use self signed ssl certificate)? What permissions / URL matches should I use in manifest ? <all_urls> didn't work

Comment: @Andrew Hall I'm looking for official documentation on not being able to run extensions on `chrome://` pages and couldn't find one. Do you happen to have links?

Comment: @Obay Sorry, this is 4 years old. The docs (and maybe implementation) have changed

Comment: Yes, this is not working anymore (Chrome Canary 69).

Answer (score 6):

The [authorized schemes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for `matches` are `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`.
Therefore, `chrome` is not a valid scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not allowed. You can't link to them from hrefs on a webpage either.

Comment: can I use a extension like a links grabber? I was trying to do so , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

@andrew-hall's solution doesn't work any more. Trying many options I was frustrated. Then thanks to @thomas-mueller, I found a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-all-extensions/ailfldpmpboolaihojfagmmfbhcgohne) which can access `chrome://extensions`:

Here is the manifest of it:

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "name": "Disable All Extensions",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.4.3",
    "description": "Disable/Enable your chrome extensions with the click of a button.",
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "management",
        "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./src/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "./public/images/appOn_16.png",
        "48": "./public/images/appOn_48.png",
        "128": "./public/images/appOn_128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "./public/images/appOff_16.png",
        "default-popup": "./public/index.html"
    },
    "author": "Blinkzy"
}
```

It's interesting it doesn't have `matches` whatsoever(not even `content_scripts`), and I was thinking it to be a mandatory field.

Comment: Doesn't actually access `chrome://` internals tho (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/)