# How to inject script into chrome history-frame?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having difficulty getting a script to execute on the `chrome://history-frame` page. Can anyone provide insight into why this is not working?

NOTE: I am trying to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` as content scripts are not being injected into this page.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.create(
{ url: 'chrome://history-frame' },
function(tab)
{
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    {
      code: 'var test = { a: 123, b: 321 }; return test;'
    },
    function(results)
    {
      console.log('r: ' + results);
    });
});
```

**manifest.json v2**

```
...

"permissions": [ "\u003Call_urls\u003E", "history", "tabs", "activeTab", "bookmarks", "downloads", "unlimitedStorage" ],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "js": [ "js/libs/jquery.min.js", "js/scripts.js" ],
  "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls\u003E" ],
  "run_at": "document_idle"
}
...
```

Thanks,
Maurice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension)

Comment: Thanks @rsanchez, I didn't see that post but I suspected what is posted there was my answer.