# Dynamic loading of content script (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have an chrome extension, with 2 content script injected by manifest and one background script.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>", "activeTab", "storage" 
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": [
                   "content/autofill/lib_generic.js",
                   "content/autofill/lib.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
        "content/specific_scripts/*"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }

}
```

`lib_generic.js` contains one function named `apply_forms(...)` (its description is not important). The function is called from `lib.js` file. But this procedure doesn't work with several pages, so for each such page a I have a special script - also with only one function named `apply_forms(...)`.

I have a function, which takes current domain as input and returns name of desired specific script or `false` if generic should be used.

There is too many files and it's logic is more complicated, so I can't just list all `(url, script)` pairs in `"content_scripts"` directive (I also don't want to inject all specific files as content script).

I've tried something like this in background (note that it's only for demonstration):

```
var url = ""; //url of current tab

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        var filename = getSpecificFilename(url);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: filename}, function() {
            //script injected
        });
    }
});
```

NOTE: getSpecificFilename(...) will always return a name

But I get `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL` on the 5th line.

Can anyone help me with this? Is it the good way to "override` function definition dynamically, or should I go different way (which one, then).

Thanks.

Comment: "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL" => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means, probably, that you're getting an `onUpdated` event on an extension/internals page (popup? options page? detached dev tools?).

One option is to filter by URL:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        if(!tab.url.match(/^http/)) { return; } // Wrong scheme
        var filename = getSpecificFilename(url);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: filename}, function() {
            //script injected
        });
    }
});
```

Another (and probably better) option is to make your content script request this injection:

```
// content script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({injectSpecific : true}, function(response) {
  // Script injected, we can proceed
  if(response.done) { apply_forms(/*...*/); }
  else { /* error handling */ }
});

// background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.injectSpecific){
    var filename = getSpecificFilename(sender.url);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {file: filename}, function() {
      sendResponse({ done: true });
    });
    return true; // Required for async sendResponse()
  }
});
```

This way you know that a content script is injected and initiated this.

Comment: in the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` call, pass `sender.tab.id` instead of `tabId`.I think you could probably get away with passing nothing too.

Comment: @Xan, Is `chrome.tabs.executeScript` the one and only function to add content scripts? Are there other solution(s)?

Comment: Is it possible to inject a content script which is a block of text from a database call, rather than from a file? Specifically, via 1) something like a call to a php script hosted locally which would pull from MySQL; or 2) via a direct connection to a local or remote database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You already have content scripts on every page, you can use them to load additional scripts with `import(chrome.runtime.getURL('other.js))`.

If you use webpack or Parcel, this is even easier to handle because they also create that `other.js` file:

- https://github.com/awesome-webextension/webpack-target-webextension
- https://parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/