# how can I get browser profile path with extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How  can I get browser (from chrome://version/)  **executable file** and **profile path** params with extension ??

Because sometimes malicious programs changed chrome profile path
(e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Eastmy\Application\chrome.exe\ instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)

Comment: It's not possible on a normal browser, the only method is to manually enable a flag: [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046796)