# Chrome extension - Show popup on a chrome page and inject js on other pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, inject

I am making a chrome extension and i want to show a popup on chrome pages (e.g., `chrome://newtab`) and inject js on other pages (e.g., `http://example.com`).

I am able to inject js on other pages like this in the `manifest.json`:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://example.com/", "<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"]
        }
    ],
...
```

But chrome wouldn't let the extension to inject js on the `chrome://` pages, So i want to show a popup on that pages.

So, Someone tell me how do i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extensions can't inject on chrome pages so you'll have to show a separate window.

Comment: Yeah i can do that but i don't want to do so. I want to show a popup, because popups are allowed on that pages

Comment: Well, like I said you can't do it in a published extension. For a personal extension there's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046796).

Comment: I am currently making it for my personal use, but if it worked correcly, i should publish it. And thanks you for giving me direction :)