# Can a chrome extension work on extensions tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

typically to match `content_scripts` everywhere we set like this:

```
  "content_scripts": {
    "matches": ["http://*","http://*"],
  }
```

or

```
  "content_scripts": {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  }
```

but they don't include pages like `chrome://extensions` or `chrome://settings`

Apparently it accepts

```
            "matches": [
                "*://extensions/*"
            ],
```

or

```
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ],
```

as well but that isn't a match for the extensions tab.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046796/865220) is not working anymore so please reopen.

Comment: **Why** do you want to inject content scripts into extension tabs? (your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me)

Comment: @ThomasMueller How do you write an extension on these pages then ?

Comment: What does your extension do on these pages? That's what I would like to know.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Help use keys betters. Basically automate stuff . many things like improve search etc. Ok one easy example is to toggle to off state all my 500 odd extensions at once. You sound like a fully organised man, I would be curious what tools you use for all these stuff ? Other options I have is fork chrome codebase and rebuild these pages as per my needs. But I don't want to go that far if this can be done via an extension.

Comment: I knew it, it's an XY problem. But now that you've told us what your X is, we're finally getting somewhere. - "Ok one easy example is to toggle to off state all my 500 odd extensions at once." - [Disable All Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-all-extensions/ailfldpmpboolaihojfagmmfbhcgohne) (I haven't tried it, but it was last updated on 6 February 2023, so it should still work)

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thanks for pulling that out. I  got so engrossed about solving this problem myself that I forgot to search existing ones . Ah interesting, its manifest v3 and it doesn't have matches whatsoever. Let me share the full manifest as answer(too big for a comment).

Comment: Solution(Manifest V3): https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457384/865220