# How to run content script code on an HTML file locally hosted by Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to run a simple alert on newly created tabs. 
A content script which alerts 'hello' works perfectly if the page is on a server for example http://www.google.com, but it doesn't work if the HTML page is hosted in the extension

manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "Alerter",
    "description" : "Opens an alert !",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["/js/content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : ["tabs"]
}
```

content_script.js

```
alert('Hello!');
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"/html/test.html"});
chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com"});
```

test.html

```
<b> I am a file locally hosted on extension ! </b>
```

You will notice that the page of Google alerts a greeting message, while test.html doesn't.

Why is this happening, and how to execute the alert on 'test.html' ?

 
 *Edit based on 'valuable' post's comments:*  
**If the documentation is wrong and we cannot inject code to chrome-extension urls, is there a workaround or alternative to achieve the same target ?**

Comment: Content scripts don't run on `chrome-extension:` urls, despite what the docs may say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196258

Comment: I'm sure @rsanchez is correct, but it might be worth trying adding chrome-extension://*/* as an explicit match just in case.

Comment: @pinoyyid, I already tried it, but this also failed :(

Comment: Your content script won't run but why would you need it to? Just put your js directly into `test.html`.

Comment: @hiattp, I've filtered the issue details to create a basic scenario for readability, the real code has a more complex scenario where I want to inject code on locally hosted pages, and the real injected code will be available only in runtime (i.e. I don't know it in advance, it's a code retrieved from backend in runtime !). So the main question is why despite it's clearly stated in documentation that it can be injected on chrom-extension: this isn't happening ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir As I told you above, the documentation is just wrong. If you read the answers and comments to the question I linked you'll find a link to an open issue in Chromium to correct the documentation.

Comment: @rsanchez Isn't there any workaround ? or an alternative to inject the code in chrome-extension urls ?

Comment: I don't get why you need to run a content script on a page from an extension you own. You can simply add a `<script>` tag pointing to a js file in your extension.

Comment: Kindly check my reply to @hiattp above .. quote: "I don't know the injected code in advance, it's a code retrieved from backend in runtime"

Comment: It seems like you'll have to achieve this with messages