# Chrome extension : contentscript not working on local page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm working on an extension which opens up a **file.html** from the Browser Action's popup. file.html is located in the extension's folder.

Let's say my **contentscript.js** is simply

```
alert("Hello");
```

And my **manifest.json** contains (among other things)

```
"content_scripts": 
    [
        {
        "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "js" : [ "contentscript.js" ],
        }
    ],
```

Now, the alert shows up on every page I'm visiting, even file.html when opened normally. But the alert (or anything from the contentscript) doesn't show up when opened from this URL :

> chrome-extension://cfhlgeljdipnicgineoheoihdofhnlef/page.html

I'm not sure how to make it accept the contentscript, any help will be appreciated.

EDIT : topic already discussed here :
[Does content_scripts matches "chrome-extension://*/*" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196258/does-content-scripts-matches-chrome-extension-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API docs:

> content script matching are based on a set of URLs defined by match
>   patterns. A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a
>   **permitted scheme (http, https, file, or ftp**, and that can contain '*' characters. The special pattern `<all_urls>` matches any URL that
>   starts with a permitted scheme.

`chrome-extension` is not a supported scheme, and therefore will not work.