# How execute Tampermonkey script under an IE Tab Page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I´m writing a script for use with the Tampermonkey Chrome Extension and I intent this script runs under a page displayed on browser with IE Tab Chrome Extension but I could´nt define a @match pattern that causes my Tampermonkey runs when the page is loaded.

Assuming the page address is: http://www.fakehost.com/mypage.html

If I load this page without use IE Tab Extension and use:

```
// @match http://www.fakehost.com/mypage.html*
```

Then the Tampermonkey "catches" the loadind of page and it works fine, but if I load the page using IE Tab then Tampermokey does not recognizes the loading of page and the script not run.

When I use IE Tab, the address displayed on Chrome address input is:

```
chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmifkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=http://fakehost.com/mypage.html
```

(the hehijbfgi... is IE Tab Extension id) and the IE Tab shows an additional address input containing the correct url (http://fakehost.com/mypage.html).

Following the Tampermonkey reference about match patterns, I´ve tried use the following patterns:

```
// @match chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmifkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=http://fakehost.com/mypage.html*

// @match *://hehijbfgiekmifkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=http://fakehost.com/mypage.html*
```

But Tampermonkey continues not recognizing the loading of 'IE Tabbed' page.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Extensions in Chrome cannot run on other extensions' pages, that is Tampermonkey can't run on IETab's pages, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does content\_scripts matches "chrome-extension://\*/\*" work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196258/does-content-scripts-matches-chrome-extension-work)

Comment: This is the same issue as in the linked duplicate. See also [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension).