# Userscript with @match chrome-extension://

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

When I try to install a userscript with (@match) URL that begins with "chrome-extension://" Google Chrome says "invalid script header" and will not allow me to install.

Is it possible to get a userscript running on a chrome-extension:// url?

Comment: @Brock Adams Not sure what it could be, when I use the following code with normal URL it works fine, with chrome-extension:// it won't let me install, can you verify this installs for you?    `// ==UserScript==
    // @name       My Fancy New Userscript
    // @match      chrome-extension://*/*
    // ==/UserScript==`

Comment: Never mind.  Chrome docs only *say* that they are allowed.  But that is wrong; they aren't actually.  See the answer(s) below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I modify chrome://extensions/ page with JavaScript(user script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148487/can-i-modify-chrome-extensions-page-with-javascriptuser-script)

Answer (score 3):

This question is a near duplicate of:

- [Can I modify chrome://extensions/ page with JavaScript(user script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148487/can-i-modify-chrome-extensions-page-with-javascriptuser-script)
- [Does content_scripts matches "chrome-extension://*/*" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196258/does-content-scripts-matches-chrome-extension-work)

The answer seems to be **No.**  Chrome userscripts, content scripts, and Tampermonkey scripts cannot be run on `chrome:` or `chrome-extension:` pages.

You will get an `Invalid script header.` message or an `Invalid scheme.` alert depending on how you attempt to install the script (or extension with content script).

This is **despite** the fact that [the documentation clearly states](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html):

> `chrome-extension://*/*`  Matches any URL pointing to an extension (the first * represents a filter for extension IDs, the second for paths).
>   (example:) `chrome-extension://askla...asdf/options.html`

There are two relevant bugs that suggest that this is a documentation error and not a valid or planned feature.  See/watch:

- [Issue 124004: content_scripts "`chrome-extension://*/*`" gives Invalid value](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124004)
- [Issue 153245: Docs need to clarify when you can use which schemes with match patterns.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153245)

Comment: i think it's worth noting that chrome extensions are local files, so we can simply go modify them directly vs actually needing to use a tampermonkey approach... and if the extension references any external urls, those are fair game for tampermonkey... so either way, we have a clear shot at applying our desired mods